# Login users with username and password auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0

I want to create custom login in reactjs not using auth0 page.

Here is my code

```
const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

const handleLogin = (username: string, password: string) => {
   loginWithRedirect({
     authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/dashboard",
        username: username,
        password: password,
        connection: "Username-Password-Authentication"
     },
   })
}
```

But it is still opening auth0 universal popup login form. I want directly to login my user in my form and go to dashboard as logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I didn't use Auth0 yet, but I read the documentation.
It looks like you are using "loginWithRedirect" so it means you are using universal login that's the reason for the pop up.

If you want your own form, you probably need to choose grant types flow "password".
https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/resource-owner-password-flow
But as I understand it is not the recommended one :)

Hope it helps.